# omp sum reduction not updating variable

Tags: fortran, openmp, fortran90

I am having issues using the OpenMP sum reduction in my code.

`en_par = 0.0d0`

```
!$omp parallel do reduction(+:en_par) default(private) shared(r,listvar,it,ic)  

!--- loop over neighboring cells
do cell_index = 1,26       

   !-- new_cell is an int. Neighbor of cell ic
   new_cell = listvar%cv(cell_index,ic)%cnum

   !--- loop over atoms in cell neigh_cell
   do j = 1, listvar%cl(new_cell)%num

      !--- pick particle in the cell list
      !--- particle is an integer
      particle = listvar%cl(new_cell)%cmem(j)

      !--- obtain displacements
      !--- apply minimum image here
      !--- min variables are doubls
      dx = r(1,particle)-r(1,it)-listvar%cv(cell_index,ic)%min_x
      dy = r(2,particle)-r(2,it)-listvar%cv(cell_index,ic)%min_y
      dz = r(3,particle)-r(3,it)-listvar%cv(cell_index,ic)%min_z

      dxmin = r(1,particle)-r(1,it)
      dymin = r(2,particle)-r(2,it)
      dzmin = r(3,particle)-r(3,it)


      dr2 = dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz
      if(dr2.lt.param%rcut2)then

         dr2i  = 1.0d0/dr2
         dr6i  = dr2i*dr2i*dr2i
         dr12i = dr6i*dr6i
         en_par = en_par + dr12i-dr6i


      endif
   enddo 
   print*,'enpar inside',en_par      
enddo
!$omp end parallel do
```

Whenever I compile and run this using `-fopenmp`, `en_par` is printed to the screen as `0.0`. However when ran in serial execution, the value is not zero. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Does `en_par` have the correct value when you run the code without OpenMP ?

Answer (score 2):

The reduction variable (here `en_par`) is not valid to access inside the `parallel do`, you have to print it after it finishes.

Comment: Even when I print it after the parallel region, it is zero.

Comment: Then there are more problems in there, but the restriction in my answer is true. Check that all other variables have their expected values.